# Why did Dolan the 37th say "Every generation.... the world?

Tags: the-last-witch-hunter

In *The Last Witch Hunter (2015)*, Kaulder and Dolan the 37th search Belial in the Witch council database:

> Dolan the 37th: Born Baltasar Ketola. Goes by Belial. Finnish
>   national.
>
> Kaulder: He's the one Ellic was working for.
>
> Dolan the 37th: The one who cursed Dolan? **Every generation has to be given their chance to destroy the world**.